# How to use cvts on an hybridModel with XREG?

Tags: r, cross-validation, hybrid

I am trying to do a cross validation using the `cvts` function from the `forecastHybrid` package using an "an" model (ARIMA + NNETAR) with external regressors.

I have two variables with 100 observations : Y and X

Note that:

```
length(Y) == length(X)

TRUE
```

I did this:

```
crossv =cvts(Y,
  FUN=hybridModel, models="an", a.args=list(xreg=X,n.args=list(xreg=X),
  rolling = TRUE,  windowSize = 84, maxHorizon = 1,  horizonAverage = FALSE)
```

and got this error

```
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "variable lengths differ (found for 'xregg')"
```

if I try to pass it as a function.

```
CUSTOM=function(x){hybridModel(x, models="an", a.args=list(xreg=X),n.args=list(xreg=X))}

crossv2 = cvts(Y,
              FUN=CUSTOM,
              rolling = TRUE,  
              windowSize = 84, 
              maxHorizon = 1, 
              horizonAverage = FALSE)
```

I get:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'X' not found"
```

I can, of course do cross validation separately for nnetar and arima and then averaging the cross validation forecasting but any ideas why it’s not working via `cvts` + `hybrid model` ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. We should add an other `xreg` argument in the `FUN` function. Then, a second `xreg` argument (from the `cvts` function) should be written outside the function. The value of the second `xreg` are then passed to the first `xreg`.

```
    y = ts(rnorm(100), start = c(1999,1), frequency = 12)
    x = ts(rnorm(100), start = c(1999,1), frequency = 12)

cv = cvts(y, FUN = function(z, xreg = xreg), 
  forecastHybrid::hybridModel(z,models = "an")}, 
  xreg=as.matrix(x),rolling = TRUE,  windowSize = 84, 
  maxHorizon = 1,  horizonAverage = FALSE)
```

It worked!

```
accuracy(cv)

                        ME      RMSE       MAE
Forecast Horizon  1 -0.2173456 0.9328878 0.7368945
```